# R ggplot2 bar chart facet wrap with scales=free and y axis starting at nonzero value

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm using R and the ggplot2 package to create a plot containing multiple subplots, each of which is a bar chart with error bars.  Each subplot must have a separate y scale because the min and max values vary so much with respect to the facet.  Another constraint I have is that I want the bar chart to start at non-zero values (similar to the way box plots, violin plots, or dot plots would work).  This is what I've tried thus far:

```
# SIMULATION DATA

volumes1 <- rnorm(40, mean=4, sd=0.2)
volumes2 <- rnorm(40, mean=35, sd=1)
region1 <- rep('Cerebrum', times=40)
region2 <- rep('Cerebellum', times=40)
name1 <- rep('name1', times=20)
name2 <- rep('name2', times=20)
names <- rep(c(name1, name2), times=2)
genotypes <- rep(c('g1', 'g2'), times=40)

meansData <- data.frame(name=names, genotype=genotypes, region=c(region1, region2), volume=c(volumes1, volumes2))

# GGPLOT2

library(ggplot2)
library(Hmisc)

meansPlot = ggplot(data=meansData, aes(x=name, y=volume, fill=genotype, colour=genotype))
meansPlot = (meansPlot
             + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, position=position_dodge(width=1), geom='bar')
             + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_normal, position=position_dodge(width=1), geom='errorbar', color='black', size=0.5, width=0.5))
meansPlot = (meansPlot + facet_wrap( ~ region, scales='free'))
meansPlot
```

Everything's all good except for the fact that the bar chart for some reason has to start at 0, so the differences between the bars become less visible.  Pretty ugly if you ask me.  I've tried adding in scale_y_continuous, but this only works when the plot has just 1 subplot and it also makes the bars disappear, which is obviously not desired.

Let me know if you have a solution for how to start at a non-zero value for the y-axis scaling!  It would help a lot.  Thank you.

Comment: Bar plots in ggplot2 are forced to include zero (discussed here in part, http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html). But I have two suggestions: (1) Substitute `"point"` instead of `"bar"`, to make a dotplot, or (2) Set the range manually with, for example, `coord_cartesian(ylim=c(34, 36.5))`. This would mean plotting each panel separately.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion bdemarest.  What I actually have is a Shiny app that gives the user the option of plotting either a box plot, dot plot, violin plot, or bar plot.  I always advocate for dot plots as well, but unfortunately many users prefer to look at bar plots :(  In the app the user dynamically adds regions and names to the plots, so it might be too much work to actually set the range manually for each panel separately.

Comment: You could introduce an axisbreak, for example with gap.barplot from the plotrix package?